# What are the names of the 30 ajza'?

Tags: quran

What are the names of all of the ajza' in the Quran? Aside from Juz 30, 29, 28, 26, I've seen different naming for these ajzaa, such Juz 27 being called "Qalla Fama Khatbukuma" based on the first words it begins, but other people call it Juz Adh-Dhariyat, based on the Surah it begins. Can you give me the naming based on where the first few words begin? and Juz 2 and 3 both started in Surah Al-Baqara, how did the people who name ajza on the name of the Surah name Juz 2 and 3? Jazakum Allah khayran

Comment: What is the use of this knowledge? Different people call them differently. There's no name on which there's a consensus. People who memorize the qur'an usually call a Juz', Hizb,  etc. based on the beginning words of the relevant verse. Calling it after a Surah doesn't sound correct as only a few of the ajza' actually start with the first verse of a surah even in the Kufi count.

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific names for the Ajza' in Qur'an. Actually, the reciters and learners of Qur'an came up with some names to make the referencing to Suwar (chapters) easier and more memorizable than numbers.

Names like (they are not standardly written):

Tabarak تبارك, Qad Sami' قد سمع, Al-Tharyat الذاريات, Amma عم, and Al-Ahqaf الأحقاف.

Some of them are named after the first Surah of the Juz', others are named after the first words of the first Surah in each Juz'.

But as you stated:

> [...] Juz 2 and 3 both started in Surah Al-Baqara, how did the people who name ajza on the name of the Surah name Juz 2 and 3?

Here, such conflicts occur. Several Ajza' starts through the Suwars, and that's why it is not recommended to follow such an approach with Qur'an. Stick to the numbers of Ajza' (30 in total).

---

[Source](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/153745/%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%A9)

Comment: You misunderstood. I didn't mean the Juz 2 and 3 both started throughout the surah, rather I meant that they both started in the same Surah. So how did people who use naming based on the name of the Juz manage to named Juz 2 and 3? Jazak Allah khayran

Comment: I wanted to convey the meaning of "through"; I have fixed it. They didn't name all the Ajza' but some of them since not all the Ajza' are possible to be named. One of the examples is your example. But I don't see how that would be a problem. If we supposed Juz' 2 is named X, and Juz' 3 is named Y, then when we want to read Juz' X, we start at its beginning (which is somewhere in Surah Al-Baqara), and the same goes for Y but its start is different from Juz' 2 (X). So, they would be differentiated.